# Is it possible to pass arguments to kubernetes cron job when invoking it manually?

Tags: kubernetes

I know you can run a K8 cron job manually via

`kubectl create job --from`

But I wonder if one can pass arguments as well?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
  # Create a job
  kubectl create job my-job --image=busybox

  # Create a job with command
  kubectl create job my-job --image=busybox -- date

  # Create a job from a CronJob named "a-cronjob"
  kubectl create job test-job --from=cronjob/a-cronjob
```